# Unable to obtain a new server anchor

Tags: windows-mobile, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am getting the error:

> Unable to obtain a new server anchor. Make sure that you can establish a connection to the server database and that the SelectNewAnchorCommand property of the DbServerSyncProvider is specified correctly.

This occurs while synchronizing SQL Server DB with Compact DB in Windows Mobile at this line:

```
Dim syncStats As Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncStatistics = syncAgent.Synchronize()
```

Comment: What are you connecting to? Do both sides (your device and your server) support synchronization?

Comment: I have made one smart device project in Visual Studio 2008.I used designer wizard to create synchronization between SQL Server DB(present in other computer) and Compact DB(present in the current  application) . Wizard used WCF service library to interact with the server DB.Above error occurs when i change the connection string in the app.config of WCF.

Comment: does it work if you're not changing connection strings? if you're using windows integrated security to connect to your sql server, under which account is the wcf service running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been sort out. I was not using sql 2008 and mine replicated compact DB was created from SQL Server 2008.Also the schema of Dbs were not correct.
Now the synchronization is done between sql server and compact DB.

Answer (score 0):

> I have made one smart device project in Visual Studio 2008.I used designer wizard to create synchronization between SQL Server DB(present in other computer) and Compact DB(present in the current application) . Wizard used WCF service library to interact with the server DB.Above error occurs when i change the connection string in the app.config of WCF.

The first thing that jumps out at me is that the device is not able to connect to your server DB. Whether your connection string uses *integrated security* or *includes an SQL username and password* will not matter if the *device itself* is not authorized to establish a connection to the server.

Using this different connection string, can you connect directly to the server (without using Sync)?

**Example:**

```
Private Function DatabaseConnect(ByVal connection As String) As DateTime
  Dim dateTime As DateTime = New DateTime(1900, 1, 1)
  Dim obj As New Object()
  Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT GETDATE();", New SqlConnection(connection))
    cmd.Connection.Open()
    obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
  End Using
  If (Not obj Is DBNull.Value) Then
    dateTime = DirectCast(obj, DateTime)
  End If
  Return dateTime
End Function
```

Another thing to look at: *Does this other database you are connecting to support Sync?* We have multiple databases here, including an older SQL 2000 database. It does NOT support Sync.

Try to simplify your project to narrow down where the error is occuring.

Currently, you have too many unknowns with using a Wizard, Sync, and WCF.

Comment: Thanks for explaining me the things.My problem has been sort out. I was not using sql 2008 and mine replicated compact DB was created from SQL Server 2008.also the schema of Dbs were not correct.

Comment: That's great. Mark it as the answer so others who read this can understand what things to try.